# I want to render imagefile in html. What should I do?

Tags: html, node.js

show my code in inputinfo.html and index.html

```
<...>
<table border="1">
    <label for="image">image : </label><br>
    <input type="image" name="image" src="inputtype.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="ready"><br>
</table>
<....>
```

show my code in app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const PORT = process.env.port || 8090;
const cors = require('cors');
const multer = require('multer');
const fs = require('fs');

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/images'));
app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/html', htmlRouter);
app.use('/to', toServer);
const server = app.listen(PORT, () => {
let dir = './uploadedFiles';
    if(!fs.existsSync(dir))
        fs.mkdirSync(dir);
    console.log('Start server : ' + PORT);
});
```

I want to render image files in html.
in index.html, success render image.
but inputinfo.html, fail render image.

so, I change url
before
index.html -> localhost:8090/html,
inputinfo.html -> /localhost:8090/html/inputinfo

after
inputinfo.html -> localhost:8090/html,
index.html -> /localhost:8090/html/inputinfo

in inputinfo.html, success render image, why?????
I want to render image file in all html, what should I do?
I think I control source code in app.js, don't you? but I don't know how to control source code.

Comment: it is unclear what you did ... please don't use descriptions like `i changed URL before index.html` ... instead show the full URL, like `mywebsite.com/html/index.html`